# SPFx List extension (Command set) - open custom side panel

Tags: spfx, command-set

I'm developing a SharePoint Framework (SPFx) list Extension (Command Set). After clicking on my custom action/Command I would very much like to open a side panel like in [this nice demo](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-side-panel). I haven't found any "official side panel" component, is there any?

To use the demo code linked above, I need to access some DOM element or a page placeholder. In the demo, which is a web part, they can access the DOM element.

```
export default class SidePanelWebPart extends 
BaseClientSideWebPart<ISidePanelWebPartProps> {

public render(): void {
  const element: React.ReactElement<ISidePanelProps > = React.createElement(
    SidePanel,
    {
      panelPosition: this.properties.panelPosition
    }
  );

  ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
}
```

However my Command Set list extension is a **BaseListViewCommandSet**, and I cannot find any domElement or any other element reference in **this**, **this.context** or **this.context.pageContext**.

Following [this Microsoft guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions) it should be possible to get a reference to a page holder via the **context.placeholderProvider** property.

```
this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(        PlaceholderName.Bottom)
```

Again my Command Set list extension is a **BaseListViewCommandSet**, and **this.context** does not contain a property **placeholderProvider**, neither does **this.context.pageContext**.

So I've just reverted to getting any element via plain javascript, e.g. via document.body:

```
ReactDom.render(element, document.body);
```

And it seems to work. But it feels hackish to open the side panel in this manner. But this is the best I've found so far. Any suggestions of improvements?

**Edit 2018-03-27**
To further explain. The "side panel" experience should be the same as when you use the "Copy to" and "Move to" custom actions:
[image]

Comment: what exactly do you want to do ? sorry didnt get your question :( , do you want to open a panel whenever a button in ribbon/command bar  is clicked ?

Comment: Yes, the same as happens when you use "Copy to" for an example. See the edit above with the new image.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick I found out was to open it inside a modal.

Inside your webpart typescript file, add the below import statement:

```
import MyCustomPanel from './MyCustomPanel';
```

Now, in your `onExecuteMethod`, use the code mentioned below:

```
@override
  public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
    switch (event.itemId) {      
      case 'COMMAND_2':
      const dialog: MyCustomPanel = new MyCustomPanel();
      dialog.show();      
      break;    
    }
}
```

Now, create a component file name `MyCustomPanel.tsx` and add the below code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BaseDialog, IDialogConfiguration } from '@microsoft/sp-dialog';
import {    
  Panel,
  PanelType
} from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

export default class MyCustomPanel extends BaseDialog {

  public render(): void {
    ReactDOM.render(<Panel
      isLightDismiss={ false }
      isOpen={ true }
      type={PanelType.large}
      onDismissed={ () => this.close()}
    >Hello there from my custom Panel</Panel>, this.domElement);
  }  
}
```

End result - i have a custom button named `Command Two`. See what happens when I click on it:

[image]

Comment: hey @gilroitto, did you try this in your command set ? Just for demo purpose, have kept the panel size as large using the `type={PanelType.large}` attribute. You can control the panel size with small, medium etc values as well.

Comment: I am sorry, I've been busy with other work. But I tried your solution now and it works perfectlt! Thank you. My old bount expired, but I started a new one now to award you. I have to wait 24 hours apparently before I can do so however.

Comment: whoa, no worries mate, you can simply accept the answer by ticking the checkmark against the answer and SO will do the needful.  By [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), it will also get removed from the unanswered section. Happy to help :) Cheers - Gautam.