# Can I use a SPFX ListView Command Extension to copy files from another library?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I'm looking at using the ListView Command SharePoint Framework Extension on a SharePoint document library.

Essentially all it will do is have one command called "New Project".  On selecting the command, it will prompt for a project number and a project name before creating a folder in the current document library and copying all folders/files from a templates library.

I first attempted this with Microsoft Flow, but it has no capability to add a command without a trigger or without a list item selected.

I'm assuming this should be possible with the ListView Command Extension, but just wanted to confirm before beginning the long road of working out how to do it ;)

Many thanks in advance for any advice/guidance provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed possible.

You dont need any triggers or even select a list item in the command set. The button will appear in the list ribbon. Just ensure that you have selected the deploy location of the commandset to `ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar`

You can get more details [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api)

One option for you would be to open a panel and in that panel create input form somewhat like in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/238722/8068) sample answer which was based on the example mentioned in the Microsoft documentation in the above link.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made a start on it yesterday and managed to get the file copying working. Wasn’t as simple as I’d expected because the files were in different libraries — i just needed to have two “webs” and then get the file and upload it again which doesn’t seem like the best solution, but it works.  I need some way to display the progress, so i think the dialog panel idea will be helpful there. Many thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help ! To display progress, you can use [progress indicator](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/progressindicator) of the Fabric UI. If it helped resolved your problem, you can consider [accepting it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) . Cheers !

Comment: Great, thanks, now I don't need to find a progress indicator either ;).  On a separate, but related note, I am actually having an issue where the button will only show on a modern library in a modern team site.  It won't show on a modern library in a classic site -- any thoughts on that?  Many thanks again.  I will be accepting this as the answer.

Comment: hmm, strange. Did you deploy it correctly via User Custom Action ? Are the columns in the classic team site library and modern one same ?  Ensure that you have the correct client-side-id props correct while deploying the custom action

Comment: Looking at [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions) it seems there is a known bug that "is being worked on" since March.  I've submitted a separate question for that.  Otherwise, my extension is now working, with a side dialog and a progress bar.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Darren can you share some code for the answer,i am dealing with the same situation