# Using SPFx custom property pane in SPFx extension

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions, spfx-custom-property-pane

Does anybody know, if it is possible to show the property pane in the SPFx extension?

I want to show the property pane after clicking the icon which I created in the navigation in my SharePoint online site using the SPFx extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom side panel using `Panel` control in Fluent UI and open it on click of icon in navigation.

Check below references for more information:

1. Similar thread: [SPFx List extension (Command set) - open custom side panel](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/238465/spfx-list-extension-command-set-open-custom-side-panel)
2. [Fluent UI documentation - Panel](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/panel)

Comment: You can also show the custom dialogs within SPFx solution. Check this documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/using-custom-dialogs-with-spfx